# Seeding error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I'm seeding my database with laravel but i get this error. To remove it i need to comment the mutator part of the model

```
public function setBirthdayAttribute($value)
    {   
        $this->attributes['birthday'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public function setFirstHireAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['first_hire'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```

How can i fix it? I'm getting crazy

Thank you

Valerio

Comment: birthday or first_hire type is string in migration/db

Comment: No, its no. Its a date: `$table->date('first_hire');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function setBirthdayAttribute($value)
    {   
        $this->attributes['birthday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value));
    }

    public function setFirstHireAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['first_hire'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value));
    }
```

Comment: I get this error: **strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**

Comment: What does $value contain? dd($value);

Comment: It's not Blade, it's Vue.js project based on Laravel backend

Comment: blade means your view code...from where you are sending date.